# I can not do anything on my google cloud storage

Tags: browser, google-cloud-storage, storage

I want to geting start with google cloud storage ,After I created my first project then I try to use google cloud storage.I try to create a bucket but after I clicked Navigation menu->Cloud storage->Buckets It show this screen[my problem

[image: 1]

I can not create a bucket or upload file and folder.How I can fix this. Thank you

I try to refresh upload file and folder but I can not do anything. If I click or do some interaction in this page it will show me this

[image: 2]

Comment: I have provided an answer below.please check

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have Requester Pays feature enabled in your project.Once this feature has enabled, every request needs to define which project is to be billed for that request. Kindly refer to this document on  [Requester Pay](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/requester-pays#requirements) to know more about this feature.

> Normally, the project owner of the resource is billed for these
> charges; however, if the requester provides a billing project with
> their request, the requester's project is billed instead. With
> Requester Pays enabled on your bucket, you can require requesters to
> include a billing project in their requests, thus billing the
> requester's project. Enabling Requester Pays is useful, for example,
> if you have a lot of data you want to make available to users, but you
> don't want to be charged for their access to that data

If you want to disable Requester Pays on your bucket,Refer this document on [Use Requester Pays](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-requester-pays#set)